# help say something like this "I don't saw the toothpick on food and get choked"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I need to construct a sentence but I don't know the right way: "I don't saw the toothpick on food and get choked"

Comment: Please, first remove that toothpick from your throat!

Comment: I'm guessing you are not _sawing_ the toothpick. You _didn't see_ it. And it wasn't _on food_, it was _on the food_ or _in the food_. As a result, _you choked_, you did not _get chocked_ (that would mean someone else choked you, which would only happen if they were angry that you did not notice their favourite toothpick...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which it was you didn't see, you could say

> I didn't see the food on the toothpick, and I choked on it. [the food]

or

> I didn't see the toothpick in the food, and I choked on it. [the toothpick]